# Consuming AX webservice through PHP with multiple key fields with the same name

Tags: php, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I'm trying to consume a webservice in AX 2009 through PHP, have done that before without any problem, this time I need to produce an XML with multiple keys with the same name, for the update part I found a working solution, but I need to select the record before I update it and there it fails.

I get this error message : "Client SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'DataSourceName' property"

This is the XML for the request :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/QueryCriteria" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/QueryCriteria" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="QueryCriteria" type="QueryCriteria" /> 
- <xsd:complexType name="QueryCriteria">
- <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xsd:element name="CriteriaElement" type="CriteriaElement" /> 
  </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
- <xsd:complexType name="CriteriaElement">
- <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="DataSourceName" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="FieldName" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Operator" type="Operator" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Value1" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Value2" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
  </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
- <xsd:simpleType name="Operator">
- <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:enumeration value="Equal" /> 
  <xsd:enumeration value="NotEqual" /> 
  <xsd:enumeration value="Greater" /> 
  <xsd:enumeration value="GreaterOrEqual" /> 
  <xsd:enumeration value="Less" /> 
  <xsd:enumeration value="LessOrEqual" /> 
  <xsd:enumeration value="Range" /> 
  </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:schema>
```

This is the PHP code I'm trying to consume it :

```
  $CriteriaElement1 = new stdClass;
  $CriteriaElement1->DataSourceName = 'CustLoadListTrans';
  $CriteriaElement1->FieldName      = 'RefRecIdTrans';
  $CriteriaElement1->Operator       = 'Equal';
  $CriteriaElement1->Value1         = $refRecIdTrans;

  $CriteriaElement2 = new stdClass;
  $CriteriaElement2->DataSourceName = 'CustLoadListTrans';
  $CriteriaElement2->FieldName      = 'RefRecIdJour';
  $CriteriaElement2->Operator       = 'Equal';
  $CriteriaElement2->Value1         = $refRecIdJour;

  $CriteriaElement3 = new stdClass;
  $CriteriaElement3->DataSourceName = 'CustLoadListTrans';
  $CriteriaElement3->FieldName      = 'CustLoadListId';
  $CriteriaElement3->Operator       = 'Equal';
  $CriteriaElement3->Value1         = $custLoadListId;

  $QueryCriteria = new stdClass;

  $QueryCriteria->QueryCriteria->CriteriaElement[] = $CriteriaElement1;
  $QueryCriteria->QueryCriteria->CriteriaElement[] = $CriteriaElement2;
  $QueryCriteria->QueryCriteria->CriteriaElement[] = $CriteriaElement3;
```

If I replace the last three lines by this one :

```
  $QueryCriteria->QueryCriteria->CriteriaElement = $CriteriaElement1;
```

it works, but the record is selected by only one key field.

I'm using PHP Version 5.1.6

Comment: Is the error being thrown by the PHP script or by AX?

Comment: Could you share the resulting XML query?

Comment: Can you help me with where to get that Jan ?

Comment: Seems like you cannot set an array as a CriteriaElement, it expects a class. Take a look at the first comment by nodkz [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php), maybe it will give you a hint.

Comment: One more suggestion is to enclose CriteriaElement objects in a SoapVar class like this: `$CriteriaElement = new SoapVar(array($CriteriaElement1, $CriteriaElement2))` and then set it as `CriteriaElement $QueryCriteria->QueryCriteria->CriteriaElement = $CriteriaElement;`

Comment: That sort of worked Maxim ! I get this error in AX : 'EndElement' is an invalid XmlNodeType. Line 1, position 610. I get an XML in AX with the correct values, but I got a BOGUS element :   
- <ns1:CriteriaElement>
- <BOGUS xmlns="">
  <DataSourceName>CustLoadListTrans</DataSourceName> 
  <FieldName>RefRecIdTrans</FieldName> 
  <Operator>Equal</Operator> 
  <Value1>5637853008</Value1> 
  </BOGUS>
- <BOGUS xmlns="">
  <DataSourceName>CustLoadListTrans</DataSourceName> 
  <FieldName>RefRecIdJour</FieldName> 
  <Operator>Equal</Operator> 
  <Value1>5637553825</Value1> 
  </BOGUS>

Comment: Don't know where BOGUS came from, but try to specify tag name explicitly like this: `new SoapVar(array($CriteriaElement1, $CriteriaElement2), XSD_STRING, null, null, 'CriteriaElement');`

Comment: I tried something along those lines, with your version I get this notice : "Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/wwwdevelopment/html/includes/classes/custLoadListTransUpdate.php on line 92" and the result seems to hold the whole file instead of one record.

Comment: Try another way: `$CriteriaElement = array('CriteriaElement' =>array($CriteriaElement1, $CriteriaElement2)); `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95023/discussion-between-phdj-and-maxim-lazarev).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$nameSpace = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/QueryCriteria'; 

$CriteriaElement1 = array(); 
$CriteriaElement1[] = new SoapVar('CustLoadListTrans', XSD_STRING, null, $nameSpace, 'DataSourceName', $nameSpace); 
$CriteriaElement1[] = new SoapVar('RefRecIdTrans', XSD_STRING, null, $nameSpace, 'FieldName', $nameSpace); 
$CriteriaElement1[] = new SoapVar('Equal', XSD_STRING, null, $nameSpace, 'Operator', $nameSpace); 
$CriteriaElement1[] = new SoapVar($refRecIdTrans, XSD_STRING, null, $nameSpace, 'Value1', $nameSpace); 
$CriteriaElement1[] = new SoapVar('', XSD_STRING, null, $nameSpace, 'Value2', $nameSpace); 
$CriteriaElementOne = new SoapVar($CriteriaElement1, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, $nameSpace, 'CriteriaElement', $nameSpace ); 

$CriteriaElement2 = array(); 
$CriteriaElement2[] = new SoapVar('CustLoadListTrans', XSD_STRING, null, $nameSpace, 'DataSourceName', $nameSpace); 
$CriteriaElement2[] = new SoapVar('RefRecIdJour', XSD_STRING, null, $nameSpace, 'FieldName', $nameSpace); 
$CriteriaElement2[] = new SoapVar('Equal', XSD_STRING, null, $nameSpace, 'Operator', $nameSpace); 
$CriteriaElement2[] = new SoapVar($refRecIdJour, XSD_STRING, null, $nameSpace, 'Value1', $nameSpace); 
$CriteriaElement2[] = new SoapVar('', XSD_STRING, null, $nameSpace, 'Value2', $nameSpace); 
$CriteriaElementTwo = new SoapVar($CriteriaElement2, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, $nameSpace, 'CriteriaElement', $nameSpace ); 

$CriteriaElement3 = array(); 
$CriteriaElement3[] = new SoapVar('CustLoadListTrans', XSD_STRING, null, $nameSpace, 'DataSourceName', $nameSpace); 
$CriteriaElement3[] = new SoapVar('CustLoadListId', XSD_STRING, null, $nameSpace, 'FieldName', $nameSpace); 
$CriteriaElement3[] = new SoapVar('Equal', XSD_STRING, null, $nameSpace, 'Operator', $nameSpace); 
$CriteriaElement3[] = new SoapVar($custLoadListId, XSD_STRING, null, $nameSpace, 'Value1', $nameSpace); 
$CriteriaElement3[] = new SoapVar('', XSD_STRING, null, $nameSpace, 'Value2', $nameSpace); 
$CriteriaElementThree = new SoapVar($CriteriaElement3, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, $nameSpace, 'CriteriaElement', $nameSpace ); 

$parm = array(); 
$parm[] = new SoapVar($CriteriaElementOne, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, $nameSpace, 'CriteriaElement', $nameSpace); 
$parm[] = new SoapVar($CriteriaElementTwo, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, $nameSpace, 'CriteriaElement', $nameSpace); 
$parm[] = new SoapVar($CriteriaElementThree, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, $nameSpace, 'CriteriaElement', $nameSpace); 
$CriteriaElement = new SoapVar($parm, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, $nameSpace, 'CriteriaElement', $nameSpace ); 

$QueryCriteria->QueryCriteria = $CriteriaElement; 


$result = $client->find($QueryCriteria);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help Maxim !